# Database constraints validation with hibernate/dropwizard?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, dropwizard

Given this POJO

```
public class Article {
  @JsonProperty
  @NotEmpty(message = "title may not be empty")
  private String title;

  @JsonProperty
  @NotEmpty(message = "content may not be empty")
  private String content;

  @JsonProperty
  @NotNull(message = "author may not be null")
  private Author author;
}
```

What I need is a database validation to check for duplication, let's say I could write this:

```
@NotDuplicated(message = "title already exists")
private String title;
```

I want to keep the resource validation as simple as:

```
public class ArticleResource {
  @POST
  public createArticle(@Valid Article article) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But how to validate database constraints using the hibernate facilities
(automatically proper response with field errors) in a easy way. I could create a class to handle this database validation but that wouldn't integrate to hibernate validations.